# Get Depth in mm for recorded video from Kinect SDK

Tags: c++, kinect

I am using video recorded from Kinect with c++ language for my project. I am trying  to get the real world coordinates (real depth) for a point. But I don't know, if there is a function in the Kinect SDK for that purpose. So I reversed this formula:

```
BYTE b = 255 - static_cast (256  realDepth / 0x0FFF)
```

to get this:

```
realDepth = (255-b) * 0x0FFF / 256
```

I do not know if what I did is correct or not. What do you suggest?

Comment: Which SDK are you using? Microsoft SDK? If yes, which version? 1.x ([Kinect for Xbox360](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/KinectSensor.png)) or 2.x ([Kinect for Xbox One](http://compass.xbox.com/assets/3d/37/3d377852-0f21-4074-a3c2-35f418170848.jpg?n=chandler_xboxone_hardware_960x540_01.jpg))?

Comment: I am using Kinect for Windows SDK v1.7

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the code used for recording the depth video?

Comment: I used depth video from a data set on that link: http://www.sucro.org/homepage/wanghaibo/SDUFall.html

Comment: I am not able to access that page. Try to add a link to a sample video in your question (for instance, you can upload it on Dropbox and add a public link to that file... or try another file hosting service)

Comment: you can found the sample video on that link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v6e8826ndld3bzg/AADKU3rNAV0L4OgAwgwFEeoXa?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

After having seen [this video](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v6e8826ndld3bzg/AADOaxKdER_Wo-quS18Ef9hya/person10/bending/1?dl=0&preview=depth.avi), I think that you should proceed as follows:

- white pixels are the farest distance possible, which (for Kinect SDK 1.x not in near mode, i.e. default mode) is equal to 4 meters;
- black pixels can be unknown values, as well as the closest possible value, which (for Kinect SDK 1.x in default mode) is equal to 0.8 meters.

So this means that, if I have correctly guessed that those videos have been recorded in default mode, and assuming that you convert each frame in a grayscale image (each pixel value ranges from 0 to 255), you should use the following formula:

> realDepth (in meters) = ( 3.2 * grayValue / 255 ) + 0.8

This way, if `grayValue` is equal to 0 (black), then `realDepth` is 0.8 meters. While if `grayValue` is equal to 255 (white), then `realDepth` is 4 meters.

If you want the `realDepth` in millimiters, just divide it by 1000.

Note also that some black pixels can also represent an unknown value. So if `realDepth` is equal to 0.8, you cannot be sure that this is the correct value, or if it is actually an unknown one.

Comment: can i understand the 3.2 in the formula, please?

Comment: If you calculate the equation of a straight line passing through two points (i.e. [0; 0.8] and [255; 4] ) in a 2D coordinate system, with `grayValue` as abscissa and `realDepth` as ordinate, you will obtain the above formula. Take a look at [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_%28geometry%29#Cartesian_plane).